# Home button in Android studio with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, background, splash-screen, restart, android-homebutton

I have created a splash screen for my app in Android studio using kotlin. When the home button is pressed in splash screen time, the app restarts and opens the next activity i.e login activity instead of putting the app to background.

How can I put the app into background and avoid it to restart automatically when home button is pressed in splash screen time

Comment: What happens in the splash screen? Do get any exception when the app is in the background? Are you trying to launch an activity from a background thread?

Comment: Im running it in main thread only. There are no exceptions but when home button is clicked in splash screen, it opens login activity after splash screen timings given

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this code to your splash screen activity?

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    finish()
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working:(